# Events monitoring analytics app duplicate logins/ login history (Einstein Analytics)

Tags: einstein-analytics, login, einstein-analytics-dashboards, login-history

I'm using the events monitoring analytics app of pre-built dashboards. I'm looking to use the login dashboard which uses the loginwithusers dataset to see the number of logins by users and their usage.

When i look at the underlying data i can see that it captures a login sometimes a second apart. Even though only a second has gone by the events have different Request_IDs and Login_keys. How can this be? I don't want to be tracking a duplication of login. I'm sure its not possible that a user logs in at 5:20 and 43 seconds and then again at 44 seconds. I can't see a way around this as there is a unique identifier for all events. Please let me know thoughts...

It also seems to show logins at off-peak times (3am) - could login history also be including scheduled reports as a user? and someone logging in as that user?